# JRegister::merge does not give correct results

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development

I am developing a component. At the site part model, inside `getItem($pk)`

I am using:

```
$params = new JRegistry;                                
$params->loadString($this->item->params, 'JSON');                               
$this->item->params = $params;
$params =clone $this->getState('params');   
$params->merge($this->item->params);
$this->item->params = $params;
```

while in `populateState` method I created a params variable and got `default.xml` params
in a `JRegistry` object and now merge only considers backend params. 
In other words, what I do in menuitem has no effect and changes nothing.
Kian William

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, Eureka, when I used `getState()` to obtain variable I created in `populateState` of model in site part, I had to change it or assign it to a registery object so that merge could work on two registry object.

```
$params->loadString($this-getState('params'));
```

`clone()` could not change a string to reg object.

In `populateState`, I create a Registry obj, but when I assigned it to `setState` variable,  it turns back to a string again, it works now